# want to create a login session using nodejs and express

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/user');
var Verify    = require('./verify');
var request = require('request');
var response= require('response');
var fs = require('fs');
var formidable = require("formidable");
var util = require('util');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session')
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var async = require('async');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var flash = require('express-flash');
var flash = require('express-flash');
//var smtpTransport = require("nodemailer-smtp-transport");
mainRouter.use(session({secret:'session secret key'}));
mainRouter.use(flash());


mainRouter.use(bodyparser.json());
console.log('user made a fp');


mainRouter.route('/')
   .get(function(request, response){
        response.writeHead(200, {"content-type": "text;/html"})
        fs.createReadStream("./homepage.html").pipe(response);
   });
mainRouter.route('/register')
.get( function(request, response,next){
       response.writeHead(200, {"content-type": "text;/html"})
       fs.createReadStream("./signup.html").pipe(response);
 
var createHash = function(password){
 return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
};

 


passport.use('register', new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback : true
  },
  function(req, username, password,done) {
    findOrCreateUser = function(){
      // find a user in Mongo with provided username
      User.findOne({'username':username},function(err, user) {
        // In case of any error return
        if (err){
          console.log('Error in SignUp: '+err);
          return done(err);
        }
        // already exists
        if (user) {
          console.log('User already exists');
          return done(null, false, 
             req.flash('message','User Already Exists'));
        } else {
          // if there is no user with that email
          // create the user
          var newUser = new User();
          // set the user's local credentials
          newUser.username = username;
          newUser.password = createHash(password);
          newUser.email = req.param('email');
          newUser.firstName = req.param('firstName');
          newUser.lastName = req.param('lastName');
 
          // save the user
          newUser.save(function(err) {
            if (err){
              console.log('Error in Saving user: '+err);  
              throw err;  
            }
            console.log('User Registration succesful');    
            return done(null, newUser);
          });
        }
      });
    };
     
    // Delay the execution of findOrCreateUser and execute 
    // the method in the next tick of the event loop
   process.nextTick(findOrCreateUser);
}));


 .post( passport.authenticate('register', {
    successRedirect: '/login',
    failureRedirect: '/register',
    failureFlash : true 
  }));


mainRouter.route('/login')


.get(function(request, response,next){
        response.writeHead(200, {"content-type": "text;/html"})
        fs.createReadStream("./login.html").pipe(response);
        
   });  
  

 .post( function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        err: info
      });
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          err: 'Could not log in user'
        });
      }
        
      var token = Verify.getToken(user);
              /*res.status(200).json({
        status: 'Login successful!',
        success: true,
        token: token
      });*/
     if(back=='/register')
     return res.redirect ('/:mainId');
     else
     return res.redirect('back');
    });
  })(req,res,next);
});
mainRouter('/:mainId')
.get(Verify.verifyordinaryuser,function(request, response){
        response.writeHead(200, {"content-type": "text;/html"})
        fs.createReadStream("./homepage.html").pipe(response);
   });  
mainRouter('/:mainId/tr')
.get(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, function(request, response){
        response.writeHead(200, {"content-type": "text;/html"})
        fs.createReadStream("./tr.html").pipe(response);
   });     


module.exports = fpRouter;
```

error in this file is inserted as follows:-

```js
G:\EZY SCHOOLING BACKEND\expresswithmongodb\rest-server\routes\fpRouter.js:136
 .post( passport.authenticate('register', {
 ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:513:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\EZY SCHOOLING BACKEND\expresswithmongodb\rest-server\app.js:42:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! rest-server@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the rest-server@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the rest-server package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs rest-server
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls rest-server
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     G:\EZY SCHOOLING BACKEND\expresswithmongodb\rest-server\npm-debug.log
```

i am creating e commerce like website which has its backend on nodejs and db i am using is mongodb ,i have created fpRouter.js which is showing error in post of signup,please help me resolve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your error is at this line:

```js
}));


 .post( passport.authenticate('register', { // << This Line
    successRedirect: '/login',
    failureRedirect: '/register',
    failureFlash : true 
  }));
```

As there is nothing preceeding the dot at `.post(`.

Comment: thank for reply , i know the error is at this line but post function is not working , it is also not working in some lines below it,post function in this whole file is not working

Comment: @MayankJain Your post function will not work if you do not put a route before the `.post`, this is what the error is telling you. I will need more information or an error after these `.post` errors are resolved to give you any further help.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below code:-

```
 var express = require("express");
 var app = express();

 app.post("/testRoute", function(){});
```